# variable needs to work on join level

Tags: db2-400

I am getting an error with this, that 'column or global variable grc# not found' what is not correct here?

```
    SELECT "OEINH2"."IHDOCD", "OEINH2"."IHINV#", "ADRES1"."ADINTA", "ADRES1"."ADENT#", "ADRES1"."ADSFX#", adres1.adent#  concat  adres1.adsfx# as "grc#"
     FROM   
"ASTDTA"."OEINH2" "OEINH2" INNER JOIN "ASTDTA"."ADRES1" "ADRES1" ON "OEINH2"."IHGRC#"= "grc#"
     WHERE  ("OEINH2"."IHDOCD">=20160722 AND "OEINH2"."IHDOCD"<=201600801)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use column aliases in the `FROM` clause.  You can, however, repeat the expression:

```
SELECT "OEINH2"."IHDOCD", "OEINH2"."IHINV#", "ADRES1"."ADINTA", "ADRES1"."ADENT#",
       "ADRES1"."ADSFX#", adres1.adent#  concat adres1.adsfx# as "grc#"
FROM "ASTDTA"."OEINH2" "OEINH2" INNER JOIN
     "ASTDTA"."ADRES1" "ADRES1"
     ON "OEINH2"."IHGRC#"=  adres1.adent#  concat adres1.adsfx#
WHERE "OEINH2"."IHDOCD" >= 20160722 AND "OEINH2"."IHDOCD" <= 201600801;
```

Note:  Your query would be easier to read with simpler table aliases (one or two letter abbreviations of the table name) and without all the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The already accepted answer sufficiently explains the issue, but the following might have some additional value with regard to overcoming the restriction.

A derived-table expression can be used to assign an *identifier* [a *name*] to an expression, to enable reference elsewhere in the SELECT query to that identifier and to avoid repeated coding of the expression [therefore avoiding potential difficulties that can arise from required *dual* maintenance of a recurring expression]; e.g. with a Nested Table Expression (NTE) as the derived-table [syntax-checked only] in the following:

```
    SELECT "OEINH2"."IHDOCD", "OEINH2"."IHINV#"
         , NTE."ADINTA", NTE."ADENT#", NTE."ADSFX#"
         , NTE."grc#"
         /* Above two lines could be replaced with just: NTE.* */
    FROM   "ASTDTA"."OEINH2" "OEINH2"
    INNER JOIN
         ( SELECT "ADRES1"."ADINTA", "ADRES1"."ADENT#"
                , "ADRES1"."ADSFX#"
                , adres1.adent#  concat  adres1.adsfx# as "grc#"
           FROM   "ASTDTA"."ADRES1" "ADRES1"
         ) AS NTE
      ON  "OEINH2"."IHGRC#" = NTE."grc#" 
    WHERE "OEINH2"."IHDOCD" BETWEEN 20160722 AND 201600801
```